# How to access ZLIB library method in android?

Tags: android, android-ndk, zip, zlib

I have added zlib library after doing ndk-build in my android project.
But which method to call for zipping the folder in android application ?
I have used this as a zlib ndk [ZLIB NDK Files](https://github.com/ftmdevlopment/zlib)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good news: you don't need to port zlib to Android, or use NDK to build it. The [GitHub project](https://github.com/ftmdevlopment/zlib) has no value except educational sample.

Android NDK [provides](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/stable_apis.html#zlib) prebuilt libz.so and libz.a, and you should look up the standard [manual](http://www.zlib.net/manual.html) to find the methods you need.

Comment: It's worth noting that if you want something that's up to date you'll need to build one yourself. The libz.so in the NDK is actually a stub that will just load whatever is on the device, which is most cases is quite old. (the static library is old too, but I just need to update it to fix that)

Comment: @DanAlbert this may not be up to date, but probably any old implementation will be OK to zip a folder, won't it?

Comment: Correct, it isn't an issue for most cases. Just worth noting since there will be bug fixes missing that would be present in an up to date version.

Comment: @DanAlbert but one can argue that the system implementation may be updated OTA if a critical security flaw is found.

Comment: @AlexCohn yes, but how many devices will get OTA updates anyways? Only the top notch devices and only for a limited time ...

Comment: @Bondax OTA updates may really happen now, especially after "O" with Treble. But critical security updates were possible before. My remark was about a hypothetical critical security flaw in libz - which is highly improbable for a small opensource library so widely used on various platforms.