# Using C/C++ within an Android-project - Purpose? Possible use-cases?

Tags: java, android, c, kotlin, android-studio

It is possible to add different C/C++ files to an Android-Studio project.

[image]

I guess you can do everything in Java/Kotlin. So why is there this additional support for C/C++?

**What are possible use cases? When is it needed?**

Comment: Because you can't do *everything* in Java or Kotlin. The use cases are pretty much the same as for JNI.

Comment: But what concrete can't be done?

Comment: there are thousands of existing 3rd-party libraries written in C or C++ you might want to use in your Android project (example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42412663/how-to-access-zlib-library-method-in-android)

Comment: You cannot run Java code as root. You need native code. Another reason is that C, C++ or Rust is faster and so it needs less battery. So when you write a game engine like Unity or want to do crypto mining you should definitely use a native language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Android NDK](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides) can be useful for cases in which you need to access physical device components, such as sensors and touch input or other [Native API](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/stable_apis)'s or

- squeeze extra performance out of a device to achieve low latency or run computationally intensive applications, such as games or physics simulations.
- Reuse your own or other developers' C or C++ libraries.