# android .so file usage

Tags: android, android-ndk, shared-libraries

I got .so file from my C developer and a task to utilize it in Android app. There is .h file that has only this.

```
int run();
```

I read about 20 different guides and tutorials, some of them felt pretty outdated and as I have 0 experience with building C apps I am heavily confused. Based on the articles I read, this is what I did.
I created jniLibs next to my java/assets folders.
Inside I created arm64-v8a folder where I put the .so file, lets say it is called libDriver.so
Lets assume the so file is alright, I dont know it but lets assume it is.

Into my Java code I put

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("Driver");
}

public native int run();
```

Now when I run the app I got: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libDriver.so" not found

I am using gradle-8.0, Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 4, compileSdk 34 and Java 17

My main question that is not clear to me, after I read all these guides, if I need to install NDK, create .mk file and some glue layer in .c and let the ndk build it everytime I build apk or if this all should work as it is and why it does not.

Answer (score 3):

I'd start with a few steps:

1. Catch the exception from `loadLibrary` call to see where it tried to find a library
2. Check your final apk to see if your library even present inside
3. Check if your library is built for your target ABI

```
ndk {
    abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "mips"
}
```

I bet this is the answer - [How to access ZLIB library method in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42412663/how-to-access-zlib-library-method-in-android)

Comment: But do I need .mk file when I do not have any C sources, just the so ? Anyway after I printed out the exception I've got java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libz.so.1" not found: needed by /data/app/~~DQdNyFus24NwDGvY2Ib77w==/myLib.so in namespace clns-6
I assume this is a problem of the library itself or can I solve this anyhow ?

Comment: @LukasHanacek go to stage 2 - check what's inside final APK. I need more info about your build env to answer if you need mk file

Comment: yes the library is present in the apk and I have 2 builds, one for arm64-v8a when testing on real devices and x86 when testing on emulator.

Comment: @LukasHanacek and its name is `libz.so.1`, right? in what folder is it located? are abifilters correct as well?

Comment: No, its name is not libz.so.1. I assumed libz.so.1 is a missing dependancy the libDriver.so that I am loading has. When I search this name it seems this is a linux library and because Android is a very specific linux build that is missing most of common llibraries available on linux builds like Ubuntu I am assuming it is missing in Android. The libDriver.so was built by .Net platform that does not have Android support and was built for standard arm linux64. I am just searching confirmation I am not making mistake when trying to include the library into Android as I dont have experience with it

Comment: I am confused. At first you say that missing dependency is present in your final APK, then you say it's missing. So do you have this missing dependency (libz.so) in your APK or not? libz is a library of (de)compression algorithms.

Comment: Updated my answer with link to possible solution

Comment: My library.so that I am loading is present in the apk. But while loading there is error that libz.so.1 is missing, that one is not in the apk. Even if I would have it and add it into jni libs folder, it would still not be found because how can I add library with so.1

Comment: @LukasHanacek Have you read the provided link?

Comment: Yes, but does it mean the one who provided me with the .so library needs to do the linking against zlib or can I do it when I build the apk and somehow link the .so file with it so that it can use the compresison library available on the device where it will be running ?
They cannot use NDK as the sources are in C#

Comment: @LukasHanacek kinda vague question you ask me. I don't know neither who and how provides you libraries, nor what target devices are, nothing at all. If we're talking about the way how to link against `zlib.so`, I once again encourage you to read https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/stable_apis#zlib It clearly says about static and dynamic libraries. One starting point I may suggest you is to add linkage against libz explicitly in your project alongside linkage against `myLib.so`